# When i pass an array of strings from VBA to c++ and use them as keys in a map, why am i not able to retrieve data (using the keys) from the map?

Tags: c++, vba, dll

I am trying to pass 2 arrays of strings from vba to c++ and use them as keys to a nested map. The data corresponding to the keys is passed as an array of doubles. First array of strings (VolArrayTenor_Destination) contains "ON", "1W", "1M", "3M", "6M" and the other array of strings (VolArrayData_Destination) contains "ATMVOL", "25RR", "10FLY". I am trying to get the data using keys in the code and it returns a 0 value, my guess is that it cannot find the keys from the map.

```
double convert2Maps(double* VolArray_destination, BSTR* VolArrayTenor_destination, BSTR* VolArrayData_destination,
                 long VolArrayTenorLen, long VolArrayDataLen )
{

double a ,x;
BSTR* b;
BSTR* c;
map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >* nestedMap  = new map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >;
map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> > &nestedMapAlais = *nestedMap;
for (int i=0; i<VolArrayTenorLen;++i)
    for (int j=0; j<VolArrayDataLen;++j)
        {
            {
                a = *(VolArray_destination + (i * VolArrayDataLen) + (j));
                b = ((VolArrayTenor_destination + i));
                c = ((VolArrayData_destination + j));
                nestedMapAlais[*b][*c] = a;
            }
        }

BSTR ON=L"1Y";
BSTR VOLATM=L"VOLATM";

x=nestedMapAlais[ON][VOLATM];
return (x);
}
```

Comment: Your function has a memory leak.  There is no need for `new` to create the map.

Comment: When i replace map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >* nestedMap  = new map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >; with map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >* nestedMap  = map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >; or map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double> >* nestedMap; the code compiles but excel crashes when it accesses the dll.. @PaulMcKenzie Can you elaborate more on the memory leak and new?

Comment: You allocate memory, and never deallocate it.  That is a memory leak.  Don't know how to make it simpler than that.  To avoid all of that `map<BSTR, map<BSTR, double>> nestedMap;`  No need for pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks help, pls bear with my ignorance I am rather new to c++ and c, I made the suggested changes, the function still returns a '0'..

Answer (score 0):

The type `BSTR` is a pointer, so you use the address stored in the pointer as a key in the map, not the string value pointed to.

Trying to do a lookup with an identical string value, but stored at a different address will not find the original entry in the map.

In C++ it is common to use a `map<std::string, double>` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Hi Bo!, thanks for pointing out that i was passing the address as a key in the map, I have corrected the same in the code now. I have to use BSTR(instead of a string) as the input array comes from EXCEL VBA.The function still returns "0".

Comment: I even tried 
       `BSTR* ON;
        BSTR* VOLATM;
        *ON =L"ON";
        *VOLATM=L"VOLATM";
        x=nestedMap[*ON][*VOLATM];`
insted of
        `BSTR ON=L"1Y";
         BSTR VOLATM=L"VOLATM";
         x=nestedMapAlais[ON][VOLATM];`
I still get the same result..

Answer (score 0):

When handling BSTRs, keep in mind that a BSTR is not a normal string.  BSTR values must be allocated using Win32 API calls like SysAllocString(), and freed using SysFreeString().  In addition, BSTR can be NULL (which is a valid empty string).

Some suggestions:

1. Make sure your VBA arrays are fixed-sized.  Otherwise, they are stored as SAFEARRAY, not a C-style array.
2. Use proper API to allocate and free BSTRs:

   ```
   BSTR sOn = SysAllocStringW(L"1Y");
   ...
   SysFreeString(sOn);
   ```
3. Instead of dealing with BSTRs directly, convert them into strings of wide chars.  (Note that a BSTR encoding an empty string can be (but not necessarily is) a NULL pointer). Here's one example of such conversion function:

   ```
   std::wstring BstrToString(BSTR s)
   {
       return std::wstring(s, s + SysStringLen(sMyHello));
   }
   ```

To summarize:

```
map<std::wstring, map<std::wstring, double> > nestedMap;

for (int i=0; i<VolArrayTenorLen;++i)
{
    for (int j=0; j<VolArrayDataLen;++j)
    {
        double a = *(VolArray_destination + (i * VolArrayDataLen) + (j));
        BSTR b = *(VolArrayTenor_destination + i);
        BSTR c = *(VolArrayData_destination + j);
        nestedMapAlais[BstrToString(b)][BstrToString(c)] = a;
    }
}
x=nestedMapAlais[L"1Y"][L"VOLATM"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have made the changes as suggested above. Now i get an _undefined reference to `SysStringLen@4_ error. I have included the OleAuto.h file as header. I am using CodeBlocks IDE and MinGW compiler..

Comment: In MSVC, you'd need to link against OleAut32.lib: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240(v=vs.85).aspx . If all fails, you'll have to just assume that the BSTR is null-terminated (they usually are), and implement it like so: `std::wstring BstrToString(BSTR s){ return s ? s : L"" ; }`